# Can you several instances of YouTrack on the same database?

Tags: youtrack

We are a very small team trying to start a project and want to use YouTrack. Until we manage to organize a machine where YouTrack can run, we thought about installing the standalone version on each our local machines and have a single database on a network disk. Will this work ? We would be using version 2020.6, the latest available at the moment.

The InCloud version is not a solution for us because the internet connection in our remote location is poor.

Thank you !

Answer (score 0):

The setup you describe will lead to serious database corruptions and is to be avoided. Provided that you're a small team, the load YouTrack server generates on a machine it runs on is insufficient, so you can pick one of the developer machines to temporarily host YouTrack.